# Rails How do you get the name of the text box into the database instead of the boolean value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
I am new to rails and to stackoverflow.
```

The issue is I want to insert text into a database (and also email) and not bool.

Something like c# on click even. If checkbox1.checked = true variable string = "the name of the checkbox is fine here". Or anything that will get the string(happens to be  checkbox name if that helps) into the DB (the field is a string).
Here is the view file.

```
<div id="home">
  <div id="home-content">
    <div id="home-text-wrapper">
      <div id="home-text">
        <h1 class="cover-heading" id="cover-heading"> Turning Data     Into Value.</h1>
     <p id="opener">Strategic consulting and decision making  solutions.    </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="contact-row">
    <div class="col-md-12" >
       <h3>Contact Us</h3> 
            <p>Please fill out the form below to start the conversation. We will get back to you as soon as we can!</p>
                <%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
                    <% if @contact.errors.any? %>
        <div class="error_messages">
            <h2>Form is invalid</h2>
            <ul>
                 <% for message in @user.errors.full_messages %>
                <li><%= message %></li>
                    <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
                    <% end %>
            <p>
                <%= f.label :email, 'Your Email' %><br />
                <%= f.text_field :email %>
            </p>
            <p>
                <%= f.label :first_name, 'First Name' %><br />
                <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
            </p>
        <p>
          <%= f.label :last_name, 'Last Name' %><br />
          <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
        </p>
      <P>
            <%= f.label :linkedin_profile, 'Linkedin Profile' %><br />
            <%= f.text_field :linkedin_profile %>
      </P>
      <P>
            <%= f.label :business_name, 'Business Name' %><br />
            <%= f.text_field :business_name %>
      </P>
       <P>
            <%= f.label :business_website, 'Business Website' %><br />
            <%= f.text_field :business_website %>
      </P>
         <p>I want to learn more about...</p>
         <p>
           <%= f.check_box :extracting_big_data %>
           <%= f.label :extracting_big_data, "Extracting value from my Big Data" %>
         </p>
         <p>
            <%= f.check_box :gain_advantage %>
            <%= f.label :gain_advantage, "Gaining advantage over my competitors" %>
         </p>
         <p>
            <%= f.check_box :bring_new_customers %>
            <%=f.label :bring_new_customers, "Bringing in new customers" %>
        </p>
        <p>
          <%= f.check_box :offer_products_services %>
          <%= f.label :offer_products_services, "Offering new products/services to existing customers" %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <%= f.check_box :reduce_cost %>
            <%= f.label :reduce_cost, "Reducing costs" %>
        </p>
        <p>
          <%= f.check_box :better_visablity_small_business_runs %>
          <%= f.label :better_visablity_small_business_runs, "Getting better visibility into how my small business runs" %>
        </p>
        <p>
             <%= f.check_box :improve_cash_flow  %> 
             <%= f.label :improve_cash_flow, "Improving cash flow" %>
        </p>

        <p>
            <h4>Message</h4>
        </p>
        <p>
            <%= f.text_area :message %>
        </p
           <a href="mailto:thisemail@yahoo.com?suibject wanting info" >              <%= f.submit "Submit" %></a> 
        </p>

    <% end %>
   </div>
   </div>
```

My controller is...

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

 def create
 params.permit!
 @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
   if @contact.save
    redirect_to "/contacts", :notice => "Thanks for your messsage."
   else
    render "new"
   if @message.save
   ContactMailer.message(@message).deliver_now
   redirect_to "/message", :noitce => "Thanks for your email."
  end

 end

end


def contact

email = params["email"]
#  first_name = params["first_name"]
end
def index
 @contact = Contact.new
end

def new     
   @contact = Contact.new
   email = params["email"]
end
 def improve_cash_flow 

  @improve_cash_flow = "improve_cash_flow"

 end
 def show
 # @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
 if @contact.save
 flash[:notice] = 'Thanks for Your Message.'
 format.html {redirect_to root_path}
end
end

def set_contact
@contact=Contact.find(params[:id])



end
private
  def contact_params
   params.require(:contact).permit(:email, :first_name, :last_name,   :linkedin_profile, :business_name, :business_website, :message)
end
```

I at this point I am about to give up on the idea of getting the checkbox name into the database. Any help would be appreciated!
 Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, RoR doesn't communicate with the server the way Webforms do, so achieving the solution that you'd like to may not be possible.

The Rails way would be to disassociate those fields from the `form_for @contact` form by turning `f.check_box` to `check_box_tag` and in your controller do something like:

```
def create
  ...
  if params[:extracting_big_data]
   contact.extracting_big_data = "extracting_big_data"
  end
  ...
  other_assignements = "other_values" if other_checks
  ...
  more_assignments
  ...
  if contact.save
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

Assuming your column for extracting_big_date is already of type `string`.

Also, I don't think you should `permit!`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. I do appropriate it!